# How to resolve -lPods not found?

Tags: ios, xcode5, cocoapods

So I am using pre-implemented project call FreeRDP. I have build the project correctly and it works. I want to use some external libraries and want to manage them using cocoa pods. I go through the process of creating my pod file and it goes through successful. It's not until that I build that I get a error saying that the library -lPods can not be found.

I can't seem to find a good solution from Cocoapods that resolves this. Would anyone know how to fix this?

My pod file looks like this :

> platform :ios, "6.0"
>
> target :Test do
>     pod 'EasyTableView', '~> 1.1.1'
>
> end

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered a very same issue. Try the following approach:

After opening your workspace, select the Pods project.

Select the Build settings tab and change the Build Active Architecture Only to No. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Weirdly mine was already set to No, I switched it to Yes and now it builds. I will need to test more on this in the morning.

Comment: FINALLY. Mine was set to NO, set to YES successful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your taget Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click . Add $(inherited) to a new line.It can work.